# Extending a class and handling a final variable in multiple constructors

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to extend a class to have a slight variation in implementation. Now there is a final variable in this parent class as:

```
private final float mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 4;
```

defined at the class level and I want to supply a custom value to this variable from my child class. As this variable is final I am changing it to be initialized from the constructor. I have two constructors here:

```
public HorizontalCirclePagerIndicatorDecoration()
```

referenced as:

```
public HorizontalCirclePagerIndicatorDecoration() {
    mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 4;
}
```

and

```
public HorizontalCirclePagerIndicatorDecoration(int colorActive, int colorInactive, int mIndicatorItemLength)
```

The first constructor is default, the second one I want to access from my child class and set custom values using the super keyword from the child class like:

```
public TPagerIndicator(int colorActive, int colorInactive) {
    super(colorActive, colorInactive, mIndicatorItemLength);
}
```

My child class signature being like:

```
TPagerIndicator extends HorizontalCirclePagerIndicatorDecoration
```

However I am getting an error here as: Cannot reference `TPagerIndicator.mIndicatorItemLength` before supertype constructor has been called.

Now I think I will have to remove the final modifier on the

```
private final float mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 4;
```

in the parent class. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: In the call to super, you are passing the variable itself (`mIndicatorItemLength`) before the call to super is completed.. there's no need. Why not make a constructor that doesn't have that parameter as well?

Comment: So you removed the inline initialization? Doesn't seem so by the question. But yeah, you can't just pass to the super constructor the same property that it will initialize

Comment: Yes I removed the inline init because the variable is final I cannot reassign it in the secondary constructor

Comment: @Brandon, pardon me I did not quite get you..

Comment: @User3; I was saying to make another constructor that sets the value just like your default constructor.. then you can call it instead.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon - It was late in night and I goofed up, actually that value should have come from the caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the correct approach. As you know, the subclass must at least call one superclass constructor. Using a final property which is still not initialized (`mIndicatorItemLength`) is not permitted in Java.

```
class HorizontalCirclePagerIndicatorDecoration {
   ...
   private final float mIndicatorItemLength;

   HorizontalCirclePagerIndicatorDecoration() {
      mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 4;
   }

   HorizontalCirclePagerIndicatorDecoration(
         final int colorActive, 
         final int colorInactive, 
         final int mIndicatorItemLength) {
      ...
      this.mIndicatorItemLength = mIndicatorItemLength;
   }

   ...
}
```

---

```
class TPagerIndicator extends HorizontalCirclePagerIndicatorDecoration {
   TPagerIndicator(
         final int colorActive,
         final int colorInactive) {
      super(colorActive, colorInactive, 12.3F /* Explicit set */);
   }

   TPagerIndicator(
         final int colorActive,
         final int colorInactive
         final int mIndicatorItemLength) {
      super(colorActive, colorInactive, mIndicatorItemLength /* Input set */);
   }

   ...
}
```